# String Padding not producing desired even alignment

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio, fonts, padding

My desired end result will change my strings (used in a message box) from...

```
Kiwi: Green
Orange: Orange
```

...to...

```
Kiwi:      Green
Orange:    Orange
```

Applying `PadRight()` to the first column (e.g. `"Kiwi:"`) *almost* works, however, my default font, Microsoft Sans Serif, doesn't have evenly spaced characters so the second "column" isn't applied.

Does there exist a fix for aligning my second "column"?

Other attempted solutions:

1. I haven't been able to figure out how to change the font (i.e. even character width font) of my message box though it is undesirable in that it would be inconsistent with the rest of my application.
2. Programmatically generating a list view or grid view container in a programmatically generated dialog box seems very long-winded. I'm hoping for a simpler alternative.

Comment: You need to make your own dialog box. It doesn't have to be programmatically defined..

Comment: @Blorgbeard Understood. Just wanted to be sure their wasn't a solution that I could apply on a per string basis. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If constructing your own MessageBox seems a bit excessive, you could try this:

```
MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Kiwi:{0}Green{1}Orange:{0}Orange", vbTab, vbNewLine))
```

It's not a perfect solution, but it's a simple one.